# How can I get out from the room alive in this recreational problem(Also known as "brain teasers")?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

You are locked in a 50 by 50 by 50-foot room
which sits on 100-foot stilts. There is an open window
at the corner of the room, near the floor, with a strong
hook cemented into the floor by the window. So if you
had a 12-foot rope, you could tie one end to the hook,
and climb down the rope to freedom. (The stilts are
not accessible from the window) There are two 50-
foot lengths of rope, each cemented into the ceiling,
about 1 foot apart, near the center of the ceiling. You
are a strong, agile rope climber, good at tying knots,
and you have a sharp knife. You have no other tools
(not even clothes). The rope is strong enough to hold
your weight, but not if it is cut lengthwise. You can
survive a fall of no more than 10 feet.How do you get out alive?

I am not sure that I'm right, but if we read the question again we see these points:

1)"If I have a 100ft rope,I can climb down to freedom." This tells us the exact location of the window. If it is not at the same level of the stilts than 100 foot rope will be useless. This is means it's less than 100 feet above the floor.

2)I am strong.

3)I am an agile rope climber.

4)The most important point: *I have a sharp knife or my knife is sharp.*

So then if I tie the knife with the ropes and pull them in the directions for which they will cut of I can have both of the ropes.But the problem is if one rope get torn before the other then I can't have both of the ropes!

Comment: Add your thoughts in the question.

Comment: Although there is some geometry involved here, I wonder if [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com) might be a better place for this question.

Comment: *"So if you had a I 2-foot rope ..."* ... Should that be a "102-foot rope" (allowing $2$ feet from hook to window, then $100$ feet down to the ground; or maybe $12$ feet from hook to window, then $90$ feet down, leaving a survivable $10$-foot drop to the ground)?

Comment: **Hint.**  Too easy.  I mean, if they were ten feet apart, *that* might be a challenge.  But a foot apart?  Child's play. :-)

Comment: @BrianTung - OK, thanks to your teaser, I've been thinking about this but without any success!  What's the solution?  Or at least, more hint please?  The obviously solution of climbing up to the ceiling and then cutting both ropes doesn't work coz I cannot survive the 50 ft fall.  Does it involve making a small loop/noose?